# How to go sub-route from ShellRoute?

Tags: flutter, navigation, flutter-go-router

I am using ShellRoute to control BottomNavigationBar. It works fine. But when I try `context.go` I get the message that the given path was not found.

```dart
 static final _rootNavigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
  static final _shellNavigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

  static final GoRouter router = GoRouter(
    initialLocation: AppRoutes.home,
    debugLogDiagnostics: true,
    navigatorKey: _rootNavigatorKey,
    routes: [
      ShellRoute(
        navigatorKey: _shellNavigatorKey,
        builder: (context, state, child) {
          return BlocProvider(
            create: (context) => NavigationCubit(),
            child: MainScreen(child: child),
          );
        },
        routes: [
          GoRoute(
            parentNavigatorKey: _shellNavigatorKey,
            path: AppRoutes.home,
            pageBuilder: (context, state) => const NoTransitionPage(
              child: HomeScreen(),
            ),
            routes: [
              GoRoute(
                parentNavigatorKey: _shellNavigatorKey,
                path: AppRoutes.homeDetails,
                builder: (context, state) => const HomeDetailsScreen(),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          GoRoute(
            parentNavigatorKey: _shellNavigatorKey,
            path: AppRoutes.profile,
            pageBuilder: (context, state) => const NoTransitionPage(
              child: ProfileScreen(),
            ),
            routes: [
              GoRoute(
                parentNavigatorKey: _shellNavigatorKey,
                path: AppRoutes.profileDetails,
                builder: (context, state) => const ProfileDetailsScreen(),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          GoRoute(
            parentNavigatorKey: _shellNavigatorKey,
            path: AppRoutes.settings,
            pageBuilder: (context, state) => const NoTransitionPage(
              child: SettingsScreen(),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ],
    errorBuilder: (context, state) => const ErrorScreen(),
  );
```

When i try go to `AppRoutes.homeDatails` form `AppRoutes.home`:

```dart
context.go(AppRoutes.homeDetails),
```

I got the result:

```dart
[GoRouter] No initial matches: details
```

I tried adding `parentNavigatorKey` but it didn't help.
`GoRouter.of(context).go(AppRoutes.homeDetails)` not working too.

Comment: i think it should be goNamed or pushNamed

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue, and this is what worked for me:

If you keep all the paths in AppRouter to access them from different screens of the app, make sure they are full paths, likeso:

```
class AppRouter {
  static const home = '/home';
  static const homeDetails = '/home/details';
```

However, inside your GoRouter object you should use a short path instead, without "/" for sub-routes, likeso:

```
GoRoute(
  parentNavigatorKey: _shellNavigatorKey,
  path: 'details',
  builder: (context, state) => const HomeDetailsScreen(),
),
```

This way, you can use context.go(AppRoutes.homeDetails) and it should work as expected!